# Can MongoDB connection similar to SQL connection in Java servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, jsp, servlets

I have below MongoDB connection method with mLab created and want to do the way like using MySQL to connect the database, but I don't know how to do the next step. I've searched numerous articles online about the MVC folder structure but limited sources to provide how to connect the external database.

```
    public class MongoDBTest {
    
        private MongoClientURI mongoURI;
        private MongoClient mongoClient;
        private String authorization;
        private List<Document> users = new ArrayList();
        private String owner = "owner";
        private String password = "password";
        private String connectionStringPostfix = "ds011288.mlab.com:11288/heroku_xxx";
        protected MongoCredential credential;
        protected MongoDatabase database; //MongoDB super-class initializes and shares the MongoDatabase
    
    
        //Specify the connection
        public MongoDatabase getMongoDB() {
            MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://" + this.owner + ":" + this.password + connectionStringPostfix);
            MongoDatabase db;
            try (MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri)) {
                db = client.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
    
            }
            return db;
        }
    
        public MongoDBTest(String owner, String password) throws UnknownHostException {
            this.owner = owner;
            this.password = password;
        }
// addUser method below
```

The closest resource I've found is [this](https://www.journaldev.com/4011/mongodb-java-servlet-web-application-example-tutorial) site. Should I declare it on the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>MongoDB Tutorial</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>MONGODB_HOST</param-name>
        <param-value>localhost</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>MONGODB_PORT</param-name>
        <param-value>27017</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>productlist.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

and I tried using a similar way to connect mLab in the DAO like below, but failed.

```
public UserDao(MongoClient mc) {
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://" + this.owner + ":" + this.password + connectionStringPostfix);
    this.col = mc.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase()).getCollection("User");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found that I missing @ in the `conntionStringPostfix` that I declared to connect the external server. However, I still can't connect to cloud db.

Answer (score -2):

Try to make it a configuration file, and the project runs as soon as it starts，Will this solve your problem？

Comment: Highly appreciate it if you could give me example. I'm new to this language and MongoDB. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean configure in web.xml?

Comment: Not always. As long as the project is running, you can perform mongodb configuration. For example, I use the @configuration annotation. Then use mongotemplate to manipulate mongodb. Your mongodbtest is very good. You can connect to mongodb. I think the new mongoclienturi() connection path can be more detailed. For example, I want to connect to the AA database, my new mongocrienturi（“ mongodb://127.0.0.1 : 27017 / AA ") as you know, each enterprise uses different frameworks and different solutions, and they have to explore their own solutions.

Comment: You mean use MongoUri instead of MongoClient obejct?

Comment: No, I mean, the connection path can be detailed to the database